# .NET Domain Driven Design and CSLA.NET

Tags: domain-driven-design, csla

In Eric Evans' Domain Driven Design approach, would it be a good idea to use Rocky Lhotka's CSLA.NET for designing Business Entities for Domain Layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we can do that.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I read the CSLA book, but I do recall that it has support for a N-tier model that allows you to remote your domain objects. While interesting and maybe even useful in some cases, I'd be afraid the added complexity would not be worth it. Personally I would stick with a POCO domain model with an unobtrusive ORM like NHibernate unless my requirements dictated something more complicated.